# Caused by: org.springframework.cache.Cache$ValueRetrievalException: Value for key 'test' could not be loaded using 'com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jasypt

I'm developing code **Spring Boot Jasypt** example. While running the code, I see the below error. I've taken reference to developed the code: https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot/issues/11#issuecomment-333134117.

error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'welcomeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.cache.Cache$ValueRetrievalException: Value for key 'test' could not be loaded using 'com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.caching.CachingDelegateEncryptablePropertySource$$Lambda$212/1832284192@1cb37ee4'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:376) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:548) ~[spring-context-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) [spring-boot-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386) [spring-boot-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1242) [spring-boot-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1230) [spring-boot-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at com.example.jasypt.SpringBootJasyptExternalizingApplication.main(SpringBootJasyptExternalizingApplication.java:11) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.cache.Cache$ValueRetrievalException: Value for key 'test' could not be loaded using 'com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.caching.CachingDelegateEncryptablePropertySource$$Lambda$212/1832284192@1cb37ee4'
    at org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCache.lambda$get$0(ConcurrentMapCache.java:149) ~[spring-context-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1688) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCache.get(ConcurrentMapCache.java:144) ~[spring-context-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.caching.CachingDelegateEncryptablePropertySource.getProperty(CachingDelegateEncryptablePropertySource.java:34) ~[jasypt-spring-boot-2.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.wrapper.EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper.getProperty(EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper.java:31) ~[jasypt-spring-boot-2.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:85) ~[spring-core-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:62) ~[spring-core-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.getProperty(AbstractEnvironment.java:535) ~[spring-core-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$1.getProperty(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:137) ~[spring-context-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$1.getProperty(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:133) ~[spring-context-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:85) ~[spring-core-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getPropertyAsRawString(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:74) ~[spring-core-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:145) ~[spring-core-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124) ~[spring-core-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:237) ~[spring-core-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:211) ~[spring-core-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175) ~[spring-context-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:848) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1083) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:581) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:370) ~[spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.SimplePBEConfig.getPasswordCharArray(SimplePBEConfig.java:434) ~[jasypt-1.9.2.jar:na]
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.resolveConfigurationPassword(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:783) ~[jasypt-1.9.2.jar:na]
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.cloneAndInitializeEncryptor(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:486) ~[jasypt-1.9.2.jar:na]
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor.cloneAndInitializeEncryptor(StandardPBEStringEncryptor.java:469) ~[jasypt-1.9.2.jar:na]
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.PooledPBEStringEncryptor.initialize(PooledPBEStringEncryptor.java:392) ~[jasypt-1.9.2.jar:na]
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.PooledPBEStringEncryptor.decrypt(PooledPBEStringEncryptor.java:489) ~[jasypt-1.9.2.jar:na]
    at com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.encryptor.DefaultLazyEncryptor.decrypt(DefaultLazyEncryptor.java:81) ~[jasypt-spring-boot-2.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.resolver.DefaultPropertyResolver.resolvePropertyValue(DefaultPropertyResolver.java:35) ~[jasypt-spring-boot-2.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.resolver.DefaultLazyPropertyResolver.resolvePropertyValue(DefaultLazyPropertyResolver.java:38) ~[jasypt-spring-boot-2.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.EncryptablePropertySource.getProperty(EncryptablePropertySource.java:20) ~[jasypt-spring-boot-2.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.caching.CachingDelegateEncryptablePropertySource.lambda$getProperty$0(CachingDelegateEncryptablePropertySource.java:34) ~[jasypt-spring-boot-2.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCache.lambda$get$0(ConcurrentMapCache.java:146) ~[spring-context-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
```

EncryptorConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class EncryptorConfig {
    @Bean
    public static EnvironmentStringPBEConfig environmentVariablesConfiguration() {
        EnvironmentStringPBEConfig config = new EnvironmentStringPBEConfig();
        config.setPasswordEnvName("APP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD");
        config.setAlgorithm("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
        config.setKeyObtentionIterations("1000");
        config.setPoolSize("1");
        config.setProviderName("SunJCE");
        config.setSaltGeneratorClassName("org.jasypt.salt.RandomSaltGenerator");
        config.setStringOutputType("base64");
        return config;
    }

    @Bean(name="jasyptStringEncryptor")
    public static PooledPBEStringEncryptor stringEncryptor() {
        PooledPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new PooledPBEStringEncryptor();
        encryptor.setConfig(environmentVariablesConfiguration());
        return encryptor;
    }
}
```

WelcomeController.java

```
@RestController
public class WelcomeController {
    @Value("${test}")
    private String test;

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String getSomeKey(){
        System.out.println(test);
        return test;
    }
}
```

SpringBootJasyptExternalizingApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootJasyptExternalizingApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("APP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD", "secretkey");
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootJasyptExternalizingApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the exact same issue and it may have to do with the version of springboot you are using. At the time of this writing, the springboot jasypt only had support for 2.0.x versions of Springboot.

***Jasypt integration for Spring boot 1.4.X , 1.5.X and 2.0.X***

Comment: I'm on spring-boot 2.7.0 and I needed `com.github.ulisesbocchio:jasypt-spring-boot` `3.0.*` though I went for `3.0.5` as it seemed less vulnerable.